# 'No such table: users' only in production console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to create a new user in the production rails console. Every command with 'User' returns this error:

```
 ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: users: SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"
```

But, when in the development rails console 'User' works fine. The production db has been migrated and everything works fine in the application except for this error in the console. Let me know if you need anymore information.

**Edit**

It seems like its not just users. Typing in a command like

```
Post.first
```

returns the same error for posts.

Comment: Have you definitely entered the rails console in production mode (`rails console production`)?

Comment: Yeah, for sure in the production console.

Comment: @user2759575 Here's one ;) why don't you try doing `bundle exec rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production`. What are the chances that you probably simply haven't migrated your production db.

Comment: Sounds crazy that someone is using SQLite in production.

Comment: @David that was it! For some reason i assumed heroku db was the same as production. I'm still learning ;) Thanks for the help.

Comment: @user2759575 and to follow up what Paritosh Piplewar it is advisable that when putting your application in production you shouldn't really be using SQLite. And also for the record always remember that your environment you are in is totally separate to the db that is being used. So that goes for when you intend on writing spec test. You will need to use the `rake db:test:prepare` or `rake db:test:clone_structure` commands.

Comment: Well in my gemfile i have postgresql under production. What does that mean?

Comment: In your production block of your database.yml you should have the adapter to use pg rather than sqlite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use production console in heroku , you should use this

```
heroku run console
```

instead of

```
rails console RAILS_ENV=production
```

Try out, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use something like SQLite browser to verify that the table exists and that the migration didn't fail? http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/

Comment: Well the thing is signups and logins etc all work so i assume so. I'll try this though to make sure.